# How can I consolidate this code?

Tags: excel, vba

Essentially I am filtering out 4 individual numbers from column A and copying that data into another sheet, but this code seems very tedious and I need to make sure the rows are offset so data is not lost.

```
Sheets("BS").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1226*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("BS Regulated Entities").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("BS").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1843*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("BS Regulated Entities").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("BS").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*865*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("BS Regulated Entities").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("BS").Select
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "*1223*"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("BS Regulated Entities").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Avoid `select`. If code works fine, ask on code review.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are looking at column `A` and seeing if it has certain values and, if so, pasting them below your original data set. Is this correct? If so, you can write a loop to examine that data and keep track of what row it should go with a variable. Right now, I'm thinking of something like this

```
finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xlup).row
nextRow = 1 'or wherever you want to start placing the data
for i = 1 to finalRow
    if cells(i, 1) = "*1226*" or cells(i, 1) = "*1843*" or ... then 'you get the idea
        for j = 1 to 10 'or whatever your last column happens to be
            Worksheets("BS Regulated Entity").cells(nextRow, j) = cells(i, j)
        next j
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    end if
next i
```

This is more compact and arguably easier to read. The code assumes you are already in `Worksheets("BS")`. No need to select it. Hopefully I've understood your situation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just filter all four numbers at once:

```
With Sheets("BS")
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("*1226*", "*1843*", "*865*", "*1223*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
End With

With Sheets("BS Regulated Entities")
    .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End With
```